# How to input an observable into an Angular web component

Tags: angular, web-component, angular10

Please note that this question is NOT about regular Angular components. I'm specifically asking about a reusable custom element created with Angular also called an Angular web component.

I have a reusable Angular 10 web component being hosted inside another Angular 10 web app.
Using attribute names that are dash-separated lowercase(i.e. my-data), I'm able to input a string to an Angular web component that has an @Input with lower camel case(i.e. myData).

HOST APP has the following in it's markup:

```
<my-custom-element my-data="test"></my-custom-element>
```

REUSABLE WEB COMPONENT - my-custom-element:

```
@Input() myData: string;
```

The string works fine and does get passed into the web component. Now, how do I pass an observable to the web component?
Example (this does not work as it is taking what's inside the "" as a literal string.)

HOST APP MARKUP:

```
<my-custom-element 
    my-data="test"
    fetch-event="eventsSubject.asObservable()"
></my-custom-element>
```

HOST APP COMPONENT:

```
eventsSubject: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

 handleButtonClick(event: any): void {
   this.eventsSubject.next();
}
```

REUSABLE WEB COMPONENT - my-custom-element:

```
@Input() myData: string;
@Input() fetchEvent: Observable<void>;
```

I also tried the following which also doesn't work:
[fetch-event]="eventsSubject.asObservable()"

If using @Input to pass in an observable to Angular web components is not the way to do it, please let me know. I also tried `this.elRef.nativeElement.attributes['fetchEvent'].value` which also didn't work for me.

Comment: please post your html code including script tagss

Comment: Did you try something like: eventsSubject.asObservable() | async ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of research and finding out one cannot pass in complex data into Angular Web Component via @Input, this is what I did and has worked well for me so far.

Since @Outputs of Angular Web Component **do** allow for more than just strings to be passed **out**, I created the observable inside the web component instead, immediately subscribe to listen for events, and immediately passed this to the Angular host app. Then in the host app, that observable is received via markup and used to broadcast an event to the listening web component.

**Web component**(my-custom-element is the selector being set as the name of the exported component inside ngDoBootstrap() of my app.module.ts):

```
@Output() setUpObservable = new EventEmitter<Subject<void>>();
eventsSubject: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
fetchEvent: Observable<any>;

ngOnInit(): void {
   eventsSubject: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
     fetchEvent: Observable<any>;

   this.fetchEvent = this.eventsSubject.asObservable();
       this.eventSubscription = this.fetchEvent.subscribe((x) => {
         // some code in here that I did not want to run until it was initiated by the host app
       });
       this.setUpObservable.emit(this.eventsSubject); // immediately send out the observable
}
```

**Host app markup:**

```
<my-custom-element 
    (setUpObservable)="handleSetUpObservable($event)"
></my-custom-element>
```

**Host app component:**

```
eventsSubject: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

onButtonClick(): void {
 this.eventsSubject.next(someData); // this talks to the Web component to tell it to do stuff
}

handleSetUpObservable(event: CustomEvent): void {
    this.eventsSubject = event.detail.observers[0];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your component:

```
private eventsSubject: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
public subject = eventsSubject.asObservable();    

handleButtonClick(event: any): void {
 this.eventsSubject.next();
}
```

Html:

```
<my-custom-element [myData]="subject"></my-custom-element>
```

Custom element implementation:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-custom-element'
})
export class MyCustomElement {
  @Input()
  public myData: Observable<any>;

}
```

Comment: brackets [] do not work with web component. Inputs name have to be in kebab-case in the hosting app and will be passed in as strings only. As it turns out after much research I found that one cannot pass any complex input into Angular web components.

Comment: Yeah you're right, but I don't understand why you're trying to do that in the first place when you can use the async pipe in the template to pass the value onto the child component and whatever you do with the data you can emit from the child component back to the parent